# Nextzen filter by datatype

Tags: mapzen

since Mapzen shutdown I am using Nextzen for requesting specific MapTiles from OpenStreetMap.

The Request looks like this:
https://tile.nextzen.org/tilezen/vector/v1/all/16/34970/22499.json?api_key={your_apiKey}

My question is:
Is there a way to filter the requested Data by changing a request data type like you do in Mapzen? (Already tried replacing the "all" with other statements)

This is an example how Mapzen lets you specify your requested layers:
 [image]
https://mapzen.com/documentation/search/search/#filter-your-search
Is there a similar feature in Nextzen?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible.

The image you shared is for Mapzen *Search*, which is the geocoding service that was hosted by Mapzen, and based on the [Pelias Geocoder](https://pelias.io).

The tiles hosted by Nextzen are a completely different service, which don't contain the same filtering options.